# WCF: No protocol binding matches the given address

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

There are several other questions relating to this error (most regarding relative addresses - these are not what I'm looking for as we arent using a relative address)

We have a WCF service which is deployed on several environments without issue - but on the latest installation on a closed network (using https) we are receiving the error:

> No protocol binding matches the given address 'https://domain.local/programmeservice.svc'. Protocol bindings are configured at the Site level in IIS or WAS configuration.

We can access to root of the site fine (using https), so we are pretty sure it is a configuration issue with our binding - but we're out of ideas.

The web.config configuration for the service is as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Service.BasicHttp.BindingConfig">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="SomeTestService" behaviorConfiguration="SomeTestService">
        <endpoint address="https://domain.local:443/testservice.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Service.BasicHttp.BindingConfig" contract="ISomeTestService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="SomeTestService">
                    <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
                </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
```

The full stacktrace of the error is:

> [InvalidOperationException: No protocol binding matches the given
>   address 'https://domain.local/programmeservice.svc'. Protocol bindings
>   are configured at the Site level in IIS or WAS configuration.]
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedAspNetEnvironment.GetBaseUri(String
>   transportScheme, Uri listenUri) +154751
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelListener.OnOpening()
>   +16284708    System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +255
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +72
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The ChannelDispatcher at
>   'https://domain.local/programmeservice.svc' with contract(s)
>   '"ProgrammeService"' is unable to open its IChannelListener.]
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +145
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +301    System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +130
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +301
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo
>   serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +129
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +741
>
> [ServiceActivationException: The service '/programmeservice.svc'
>   cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The
>   exception message is: The ChannelDispatcher at
>   'https://domain.local/programmeservice.svc' with contract(s)
>   '"ProgrammeService"' is unable to open its IChannelListener..]
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +607194
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) +231
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +177

Comment: does your site have an https binding in IIS manager?

Comment: Yes, https binding is set up with a valid certificate in IIS and works fine for the root site.

Comment: Another thread says the endpoint address should be relative address instead of absolute?

Comment: We're using the same absolute address fine on several other instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the unlikely event that this proves useful to anyone else - this turned out to be a problem with our build scripts which were creating endpoint addresses with extra character in them, which obviously then didnt match the bindings...*just like the error message was telling us the whole time*.

If you're seeing similar errors, triple check that the provided service endpoint address **really** matches what you've set up in IIS.